# Restcomm Docker Installation Issues

Tags: sip, restcomm

I'm trying to getting started with restcomm following this guide:

http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-docker-quick-start-guide/

but I'm facing two issues at this time:

- Cannot make SIP calls. After I run the docker run command my softphone (X-Lite) can register successfully with the server but when I try to call +1234 I receive 'Call failed to connect'. This is what I see in logs:

https://justpaste.it/tdjg

- I also can't connect to Visual Service Designer. This is what I see:

[image]

Log:

https://justpaste.it/tdjm

The docker command that I'm using is:

docker run --rm -i -t --name=restcomm-instance -v /var/log/restcomm/:/var/log/restcomm/ -e STATIC_ADDRESS="192.168.1.150" -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -e VOICERSS_KEY="fdf04434829e4e02addd8d54b69e6bc0" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp restcomm/restcomm:latest

And the servo is:

[image]

Hope you can help me.
Regards

Comment: Hi @agurodriguez, I cannot reproduce the problem. I am running the exact command and everything is working properly for me. Can you please pull again the latest container restcomm/restcomm:latest and try to run RestComm again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Restcomm Docker Quick start guide](https://www.restcomm.com/docs/connect/configuration/docker/Restcomm%20-%20Docker%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.html) has recently been updated and should now be much more straightforward to deploy Restcomm on Docker, using Docker compose.